# How to get application usage statistics on android?

Tags: android, usage-statistics

What I want is to access the time (in milliseconds) that each application is used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dig up the source to "Spare Parts" and see how they do it

(also copy it off the emulator, install it on your phone and make sure it works)

Note: while this remains accurate for the circa-2010 versions of Android about which it was written, restrictions added years later in 4.4 and 5.0 would substantially frustrate achieving this in more recent versions.

Comment: The "Spare Parts" source code has some classes from private API. And i'm not able to view how it's done...

Comment: At this moment I am able to get an event every time any application is opened by user, and i could store a timestamp, then i need to find a way to get an event to when application goes to background. And now i have this problem.

Comment: The private api's are available in source form on android.git.kernel.org  however you may or may not be able to reproduce that functionality in a way consistent with the android architects' vision of what a well behaved application can or should do.

Comment: @Joao Can you tell me, how do you get an event every time an app opens? Any idea would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Priyank I have that problem too. If i could get an evevent evey time an app opens and goes to background, i had my problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html). Did you mean by programming?

By Programming, You can check out how [SpareParts](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=blob;f=apps/SpareParts/src/com/android/spare_parts/SpareParts.java;h=099f27a9ba76e8a39accf36b45bb699e69d05b9c;hb=HEAD) does it.

Answer (score 0):

@João Lopes,Chris Stratton

Google Provide the sample code for [AppUsageStatistics Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics)

Here full of statistics base on daily weekly monthly usages.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics has a cool feature where it tracks the average time on each screen and the percentage of which screen is used most often.

Is this is good enough for you, I would suggest adding Firebase to your app, as it has a free plan, and it will automatically track your users' time. You can start [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use  [FireBase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start).